# Prevent hyperref \href from inserting spaces into target URLs containing macros

Tags: hyperref

I have noticed that some of the links my BibTeX style generates do not work because they have spaces in them. The style (apsrev4-1) hyperlinks the journal part of the reference to the DOI resolver at doi.org using something like

```
\href {\doibase 10.1234/doi.handle}{Journal 12, 1234 (1984)}
```

However, BibTeX word-wraps its output and sometimes it inserts a linebreak right behind the `\doibase` macro. In exactly these cases the resulting URL contains a space right after the expansion of that macro, e.g., `https://doi.org/ 10.1234/doi.handle`. I can reproduce the behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\base}[0]{http://www.example.com/}

\begin{document}
\href {\base test.html}{Link without space}

\href {\base
test.html}{Link with space}
\end{document}
```

If I understand correctly, there should be no difference between the two invocations because all whitespace after a macro gets ignored.

How can I make the second version behave like the first? I have tried to append `\ignorespaces` to the definition of the `\base` macro but all that does is add a literal (url-encoded) `%5Cignorespaces`.

Comment: Well you need to add a percentchar to hide the end-of-line. But I have no idea how to tell bibtex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer bibtex puts percent chars in output when it breaks lines not at spaces (there is code to handle it in url.sty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is of help to you, but when TeX reads input from .tex-input-files it inserts a character with each end of a line of input whose code-point's number in TeX's internal character encoding scheme (which either is ASCII with traditional TeX or is unicode with XeTeX- or LuaTeX based engines) equals the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`.

If the value of `\endlinechar` is outside the range of possible code-point-numbers of characters, then no character is inserted.

Usually the value of `\endlinechar` is 13(decimal) which implies that a return-character is inserted because 13(decimal) is the code-point-number of the return-character both in ASCII and in unicode. (The return-character in TeX's `^^`-notation can be denoted via `^^M`, `M` being the 13th letter of the alphabet.)

Usually the return-character has category code 5. If TeX encounters a catcode-5-character while the reading-apparatus is in state S(skipping blanks), then no token at all is inserted into the token-stream for this character. TeX's reading apparatus is switched to state S after tokenizing an explicit space-token of character code 32 and category code 10(space) and after tokenizing a control-word-token and after tokenizing a control-space `\` . If TeX encounters a catcode-5-character while the reading-apparatus is in state M(middle of line), then an explicit space-token of character code 32 and category code 10(space) is inserted into the token-stream for this character. TeX's reading-apparatus is switched to state M after tokenizing character-tokens or control-symbol-tokens other than control-spaces.  If TeX encounters a catcode-5-character while the reading-apparatus is in state N(new line), then the control-word-token `\par` is inserted into the token-stream for this character regardless the meaning/definition `\par` has. TeX's reading-apparatus is switched to state N when beginning tokenization of another line.

So you could assume that after `\base`, which is a control-word-token, the reading-apparatus is in state S and therefore insertion of the return-character due to the `\endlinechar`-thingie doesn't yield insertion of whatsoever token into the token-stream.

But the `\href`-command is somewhat special: `\href`—before reading from the .tex-input-file and tokenizing the URL-argument begins— calls macros for changing the category-code of the return-character to 13(active) and defining the active-return-character to be a macro which delivers a space-token/a character-token of category code 10(space) and character-code 32. Thus with the URL-argument of `\href` a linebreak in the .tex-input-file yields insertion of return-character-token of category code 13(active) into the token-stream.  That active return-character-token at that time is defined to be a macro which expands to a space-token.

I don't know if the following suggestion suits your workflow but probably you can assign `\endlinechar` a value outside the range of possible code-point-numbers of characters, e.g., the value -1. This way no character at all will be inserted by TeX at a line-break.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
    
\newcommand{\base}[0]{http://www.example.com/}

\begin{document}
\href {\base test.html}{Link without space}

\href {\base
test.html}{Link with space}

%Probably something like this does the trick for you:

\begingroup
\endlinechar=-1\relax
\href{\base
test.html}{What's this?}
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

But if you can search through the sources for inserting `\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax..\endgroup` everywhere, then you can also instead search through the sources for removing linebreaks after `\base`.

Probably you can define `\base` to call a macro which grabs one non-delimited argument and—assuming this is the next token—checks if that is active-return and puts it back only in case it is not. But this has some drawbacks:

- As everything must be done in terms of macro-expansion, the "lookahead" must also be done by means of macro-arguments. So the lookahead is not on the next token but is on the next macro argument. If there is a multi-token-argument wrapped in curly braces right behind `\base`, these curly braces get removed. If there is no more token suitable as macro-argument after `\base`, e.g.,  `\href{\base}{What's this?}`, then you may get error-messages with some hyperref-release.
- Only a linebreak right after the token `\base` will be treated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
\def\activereturnfork#1{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\activereturnfork[1]{%
    \forkactivereturn##1{}#1{##1}^^M^^M%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\forkactivereturn{%
    \long\def\forkactivereturn##1#1##2##3^^M^^M{##2}%
  }%
}%
\catcode`\^^M=13\relax%
\activereturnfork{^^M}%

\newcommand{\base}[0]{http://www.example.com/\activereturnfork}

\begin{document}
\href {\base test.html}{Link without space}

\href {\base
test.html}{Link without space, too}

But:

% This will not be a link to http://www.example.com/{bracesremoved}.html
% but will be a link to  http://www.example.com/bracesremoved.html :
\href {\base {bracesremoved}.html}{Link with braces removed}
% But curly braces in any case are unsafe-characters and therefore in
% urls should be encoded with percent-encoding as %7B respective %7D .

% With current \hyper@normalize (hyperref 2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links
% for LaTeX) this works by accident:
% \base/\activereturnfork takes \Hy@RemovePercentCr's \ifx for its argument
% and returns it:
\href {\base}{Attempts at creating this link may cause troubles when in future hyperref-releases internals are changed.}

\end{document}
```

Probably the best option is to modify the BibTeX-style not to do linebreaks within macro-arguments that get tokenized under non-standard category-code-régime.